# Gradle Build Failed, after inserting tess4j.jar in Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, ocr, tesseract

Hello swarm intelligence,

I tried inserting the google tesseract OCR in my Android Project for two days. After endless amount of trying I saw the wrapper lib tess4j, but inserting a up-to-date version via gradle compile 'net.sourceforge:tess4j:tess4j:x-x-x' is not possible, so I downloaded the newest .jar file and added it to my Android Studio Project. The Gradle Build worked just fine and I can now use the Classes and methods in my code. But after trying a very simple sample app I got this Error which I don't understand, can someone please explain it to me, and how to solve it?

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
public Button mStartTesseractBtn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mStartTesseractBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startTesserActBtn);
    mStartTesseractBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "In OnClick, start reading image...");
            try {
                Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
                String erg = instance.doOCR(new File("C:\\Users\\UserX\\Desktop\\scrabble-2.bmp"));
                System.out.println(erg);
            } catch (TesseractException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug] :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   C:\Users\UserX\AndroidStudioProjects\OCR\app\src\main\java\de\companyX\ocr\MainActivity.java
>   Error:(65, 42) error: cannot access BufferedImage class file for
>   java.awt.image.BufferedImage not found Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 2.871 secs
> >     Information:2 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
> >     output in console

Comment: which java version you use?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_66"

Comment: Install JDK 1.7_65 , then in project settings change java from jdk8 to jdk7/ I'm sure that would work

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but I'm despreatly searching for it. Found this on the official Oracle website and searched whole first page of google :D : "Where can I get Java 7 downloads?
July 2015: Updates for Java 7 are no longer available to the public. Oracle offers updates to Java 7 only for customers who have purchased Java support or have Oracle products that require Java 7."

Comment: tell me which system you use and I would help you find it

Comment: I see links: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: Windows10. Okay I will try it tomorrow.  Happy new year everybody! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't use this library on Android.  The library is referencing `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` which is not in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Android will not support java.awt instead you can use java.graphics ,if you are using external library add your jre in android studio,but it will not help while taking apk,better search for same library available for android

Comment: Try the Android Bitmap class.  For tesseract in Android try tess2.  It works for me.